# framework not found error

Tags: swift, xcode

I no longer needed anything from Facebook framework so I manually deleted all Facebook frameworks. Now I cannot get my app to run. I deleted all derived data, however, I still getting:

[image]

Comment: Did you add your framework using Pod?

Comment: yes I added it using pod

Comment: Clean the build folder: `Cmd`+`Option`+`Shift`+`K`. And then, clean the project `Cmd`+`Shift`+`K`. Restart Xcode and *Build & Run* again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your Pod file, And remove/delete FBSDK like this-

[image]

After removing Facebook framework do cmd+S to save your pod file again, close your open Xcode and- **pod update.**, **Install pod again.**

Comment: now it won't let me pod install, gives me this error  HGs-MacBook-Pro:jabMix1 HG$ pod install
-bash: /usr/local/bin/pod: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: did you delete you pod folder also?

Comment: no my pod folder is there and so is my pod file with no facebook inside.

Comment: I updated cocoa pods and ran pod install and I saw in the terminal it removed Facebook frameworks and is running again now.